# Storing HTML in a variable for later use in Next JS

Tags: javascript, html, next.js

In Next JS, I have code that looks something like this:

```js
function Test() {
    return (
        <section>
            <div>Test</div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

But let's say that I want to have multiple entries here, generated from code. I essentially want to replace the contents of `<section>` with precalculated HTML. Here is what I have tried:

```js
function Test() {
    let posts;
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
        posts += <div>Test</div>;
    }
    return (
        <section>{posts}</section>
    );
}
```

However, this simply produces the output `[object Object][object Object][object Object]`, which is not what I intended. I have tried surrounding the HTML with quotes and graves, but it doesn't work. I really have no idea what I'm supposed to do to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` only concatenates strings; you need to store your element objects in an array using `.push()` or `.map()`. The entire array's contents will be printed out when you call it.

This code will work:

```js
function Test() {
    const posts = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
        posts.push(<div>Test</div>);
    }
    return (
        <section>{posts}</section>
    );
}
```